# Contact form not submitting. Just refreshing. No errors...nothing

Tags: email, contact-us

Sorry if this a repeated topic, but everything I can find is out of date and not for my version.

New issue in the very long line of issues...using Magento 2.3.2. CE

The contact form is not working on our website. It is displaying fine, and all config settings are enabled and I know the email addresses are functioning because account setup, etc works.

When you enter all the details, and click 'Submit' the 'contact-us' page just refreshes with no messages or errors at all, and no mail is sent.

I am using Xstore theme, but the nuts and bolts are the same as the Magento default form. I've even replaced the Xstore 'form.phtml' with the default one and still the same result.

I have a 'contact-us' CMS page and I am using the code:

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```

as per Magento documentation.

Any ideas as to why this is happening would be gratefully received.

Thank you.

Comment: Please check in the system.log or exception.log

Comment: Have checked logs. Nothing doing.

Comment: Please ask theme vendor they can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever find a solution to this issue, as I have the same problem with the same theme? Seems the vendor is no longer supporting the theme.